# Flutter To show logged in Users details in a new Screen

Tags: flutter

Im new to flutter, im trying to create an app where it will show logged users current details thats i have on firestore. I have also provided an image of my firestore 'user profile' database wherer it has user current information.[user database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMQ3M.png)

this is what im using to login

```
 async {
    try {
 final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(                                  
            email: email, password: password);
                                if (user != null) {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => ChatScreen()));
                                }
                              } catch (e) {
                                print(e);
                              }
                            },
```

this is what im using to show current logged in user details in column. But i only get white Screen nothings displayed.

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('User Screen'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('proflies').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text('loading');
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var user;
                DocumentSnapshot myPost = snapshot.data.documents[user];
                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('${myPost['fullName']}'),
                          Text('${myPost['bio']}'),
                          Text('${myPost['gender']}'),
                          Text('${myPost['image']}'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provide a stream `Firestore.instance.collection('proflies').snapshots()`, in the `ListView.builder()` you are building every item one by one with `itemBuilder: (context, index)`, `snapshot.data.documents` is an array so you must use index for each item in that array. `snapshot.data.documents[user]` here user must be replaced with index and then you can reach concrete user's fields => example: `snapshot.data.documents[index]['fullName']`.

Comment: hi, im still seeing nothing but appbar i have changed it to DocumentSnapshot myPost = snapshot.data.documents[index]; and Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['fullName']),

Comment: Try to print that data before the Stack to see if you persist the data in firestore.

Comment: it doesnt print anything. could you take a look at the image that ive provided of my firestore database

Comment: ahh I saw the error, in your stream  ‘Firestore.instance.collection('proflies').snapshots()’ you have written proflies instead profiles.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use your index variable inside your itemBuilder loop:

change this:

```
var user
DocumentSnapshot myPost = snapshot.data.documents[user];
```

to:

```
DocumentSnapshot myPost = snapshot.data.documents[index];
```